# Nginx - Configuration inside a webroot directory

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

How can I create a configuration file on a directory inside the webroot directory if I can't or don't want to set it up on `sites-enable/domain.tld`?

Just like in Apache, we can set up a `.htaccess` inside a directory.

Comment: You can include the vhost configuration file inside your document root, but you'll still need to reload nginx for any changes to take effect. Nginx will keep the parsed info in its memory until the next reload or restart.

Comment: I see :( I can't deny the access to a folder programmatically without restarting nginx?

Comment: Also, there's no way to use a .htaccess file with Nginx. Nginx wasn't built to support them.